# Prove that there exists a basis of $V$ (infinite) containing $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space, $W$ an infinite-dimensional subspace of $V$, and $B$ a basis of $W$.  Prove that there exists a basis of $V$ containing $B$.

Here's what little I know(: by Zorn's Lemma any finite or infinite dimensional vector space has a basis.  Let $B = \{ w_1, w_2, \dots \}$ be a basis of $W$.  We want to show that $\exists$ a basis $v_1, v_2, \dots$ of $V$ containing $B$.  I think [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335019/prove-that-b-is-a-basis-of-the-space-v) is how we may want to start the problem except drawing a unique linear transformation doesn't show *containing* does it?  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995521/if-w-is-a-subspace-of-v-prove-that-there-exists-a-basis-of-v-given-a-basi) is similar for finite dimension, can this proof be extended to infinite dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Let
$$
\mathcal C=\{D\subset V : B\subset D\,\,\&\,\,\text{$D$ linearly independent}\}.
$$
Then if $\mathcal G\subset C$ a chain in $\mathcal C$ (i.e., totally ordered subset of $\mathcal C$ by "$\subset$"), then $\hat D=\bigcup \mathcal G$ is an upper bound of $\mathcal G$ and $\hat D\in\mathcal C$. Hence Zorn's Lemma is applicable, and it provides a maximal element of $\mathcal C$, which is a basis of $V$.